# store and secure password used in javamail on android

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I have to create a form in my application to request an appointment. I am using javamail to send information. I don't know how to secure my password.  Should I store a hashed password in database?

```
session=Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, new Authenticator(){
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
    return new PasswordAuthentication("user","password");               
}
```

Comment: It is highly preferable to **NOT** store plain text passwords in a database or elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you be using email for this rather than setting up a webservice?

Comment: i have to use static user/password for the hole application to send emails,i'm not retrieving them from user infrotmation.so need i to use webservice in this case?